# « d’en bas » est-il un idiome ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, société, politique

> **[J’écris d’en bas, de la partie effondrée de l’Espagne](http://www.liberation.fr/monde/2013/07/17/j-ecris-d-en-bas-de-la-partie-effondree-de-l-espagne_918998)**
>
> En 2008, enceinte de huit mois, l’écrivaine espagnole Cristina Fallarás a été licenciée par le journal où elle travaillait comme sous-directrice. C’était le début du commencement de la débâcle d’un pays où sombrerait une grande partie de ses concitoyens. En novembre 2012, Cristina a reçu une lettre de la banque : pour cause de non-paiement, celle-ci a démarré une procédure d’expulsion. La lauréate du prix Hammett 2012 du meilleur roman policier en langue espagnole décrit ici cette chute : […]

Je sais que **en bas** signifie *downstairs*. Mai je ne sais pas que **d'en bas** signifie. Pourrait-il signifier *from downstairs*, ou, extrapolé, *from the basement* ?

Comment: Comme tu as posé la question en français, j'ai répondu en français. N'hésite pas à me dire si ma réponse est trop compliquée.

Comment: @Gilles Je compris maintenant. Comme on dirait en anglais, _the scum of society_.

Comment: No! *Scum of society* is a lot more restrictive and is pejorative. *Gens d'en bas* is rather laudative and covers an unspecified part of the middle class.

Comment: @Gilles I see... Then, if it is not pejoratively used, any English equivalent you might think of, that is not pejorative? I can't think of any right now. Just _the poor_ (but maybe it's too simple like that).

Comment: The metaphor is the same as in *downtrodden*, but *gens d'en bas* doesn't have the explicit connotation that the people who are down are down because others are pushing them down. There's probably no equivalent that has the exact same scope and political overtones. Mind you, *here*, an expression that is restricted to the lower levels of the social ladder would work — where it wouldn't work is to translate *France d'en bas*. Something like “*I am writing from the lowest rung of the collapsed Spanish society*”, maybe.

Comment: @Gilles I get it. I could've thought about _downtrodden_, but didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*En bas* peut avoir un sens spatial : au rez-de-chaussée, à la cave, au pieds de la montagne, ... Mais l'expression peut aussi avoir un sens figuré, et c'est le cas ici.

Ici, *en bas* désigne les basses couches sociales, autrement dit les pauvres. La « partie effondrée de l'Espagne », ce sont des gens qui ont beaucoup perdu à cause de la crise économique, qui sont passés des classes moyennes au prolétariat. C'est la même métaphore qui place les gens les plus riches au sommet de l'échelle sociale et les gens les plus pauvres au bas de l'échelle. La description de l'article continue sur cette métaphore en parlant de « chute ».

L'auteur est une des victimes de la crise. Elle faisait autrefois partie d'une classe moyenne intellectuelle. Elle est maintenant sans argent, et écrit en tant que pauvre, en tant que personne « d'en bas » de l'échelle sociale.

L'expression « [la France d'en bas](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/France_d%E2%80%99en_bas) » s'est répandue via les discours politiques dans les années 2000. Elle est plus portée par des hommes politiques de droite, mais peut aussi être utilisée sans connotation de bord politique. « Les gens d'en bas » couvre le [prolétariat](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prol%C3%A9tariat) ainsi que des classes moyennes modestes. La limite supérieure est volontairement ambiguë, afin de permettre à une large part des classes moyennes de s'identifier aux gens « d'en bas ». En général, « d'en bas » a plutôt une connotation positive, contrairement à « pauvre » : l'idée est que les gens d'en bas sont victimes d'une société qui ne leur permet pas de prospérer.

Comment: Et moi qui avait bêtement cru que la question portait sur le d' !

Comment: @Gilles: Pourriez-vous expliciter la fonctionne et la figure de style de écrit dans : Elle est maintenant sans argent, et écrit en tant que pauvre,.... Puisque écrit n'est pas un nom, j'imaginais: Elle est maintenant sans argent, et [ELLE EST] écrit en tant que pauvre,..., mais ceci m'apparaît déraisonnable ?

Comment: Comme elle à descendu l'échelle sociale, elle y est même *en bas* Cristina Fallarás "n'est plus de la Haute" (familièrement on omet d'ajouter Société dans ce contexte).

Comment: @LePressentiment « … et [elle] écrit … »